# BufferedReader retorna sempre null

Tags: java, cliente-servidor, tcp

Apesar de algumas perguntas já existirem com o assunto similar, não consegui uma resposta exata, por isso recorro mais uma vez ao *Stack*.

Estou a desenvolver um sistema cliente-servidor, já tinha o projeto mais adiantado, e resolvi comecar do início:

**CLIENTE**

Tive que eliminar algumas linhas de codigo para perceber onde se encontrava o erro. O erro encontra-se quando faço uso do `in.read()` ou `in.readLine()`, acaba sempre por retornar uma excepção.

```
private Socket socket = null;
private int port = 2048;
private String host;
private Utilizador utilizador;
private Mensagem mensagemServidor;
private static PrintWriter out = null;
private static BufferedReader in = null;
//  private static ObjectOutputStream objectOut;
//private static ObjectInputStream objectIn;
private static int vefVariable;
private static String mensagemServidorThr;

/**
 * Construtor para ser usado na conecção ao servidor pela primeira vez pelo
 * utilizador
 *
 * @param hostInstace
 * @param user
 */
public Socket_Client(String hostInstace, Utilizador user) {
    this.host = hostInstace;
    this.utilizador = user;
}

/**
 * Construtor para ser usado para envio de mensagem do cliente para o
 * servidor
 *
 * @param user utilizador que envia a mensagem
 * @param mensagem mensagem que o utilizador mandou.
 */
public Socket_Client(Mensagem mensagem) {
    this.mensagemServidor = mensagem;
}

public void connecttoServer() throws IOException {

    try {
        socket = new Socket(host, port);
        out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        System.err.println("Não existe informação com o servidor" + host);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Não existe informação com o servidor" + host);

    }
    out.println("tudobem");
    System.out.println(in.read());
}
```

**SERVIDOR**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    ServerSocket srvSckt = null;
    int porto = 2048;
    boolean listening = true;

    //conecao ao servidor
    try {
        srvSckt = new ServerSocket(porto);
        System.out.println("Conecção ao Servidor efectuada com sucesso!");
    }catch(IOException ex) {
        System.err.println("Impossível coneção a porta \t" +porto);
    }
    Socket clientSocket = null;

    clientSocket = srvSckt.accept();
}
```

Penso que falte a comunicacao com a parte do servidor, mas ja tentei e continua a nao funcionar, desta vez nao me aparece os elementos da interface grafica.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O servidor aceita a conexão mas logo em seguida o programa é terminado, portanto a conexão vai ser fechada.

O método `readLine` retorna `null` (`read` retorna -1) pois a conexão foi fechada logo após ter sido aberta.

Aqui o trecho do código em questão (com problema) comentado:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    ...

    clientSocket = srvSckt.accept();  // aceita a conexão
}                                     // main, programa, conexão terminam/fecham
```

em outras palavras, está faltando o código que vai tratar da comunicação com o cliente. Pelo menos tem que fazer uma leitura do `clientSocket` para ler a frase enviada pelo cliente e, em seguida enviar a resposta para o cliente. Normalmente isso ocorre num loop até a conexão ser fechada, dependendo do protocolo usado (por exemplo: cliente envia "exit" para terminar a conexão).

Exemplo (muito simplificado):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    ...

    clientSocket = srvSckt.accept();

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream()));

    String str = in.readLine();
    System.out.printf("Servidor recebeu \"%s\"\n", str);
    out.write('X');
    out.flush();

    // outros comandos, se terminar o main provavelmente o cliente
    // não irá receber a respota
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    clientSocket.close();
}
```